# How can I space only one axis away from other axes using matplotlib and gridspec?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib and grispec to plot 4 axes, three of which I want tight to one another and the last one I want spaced a little bit away from the above three. Reason being is that I want the top three to share the same x-axis units, and the bottom one to have different x-axis units. I've tried using `gs.update` right after the third axis, but this spaced out all the axis from one another, instead of the bottom fourth axis from the top three.

Is there a simple gridspec/matplotlib command that I'm missing, or do I have to hack around this somehow?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,12))
gs1=fig.add_gridspec(nrows=4, ncols=2, hspace=0.0)

ax2=fig.add_subplot(gs1[1,:])
ax1=fig.add_subplot(gs1[0,:], sharey=ax2)
ax3=fig.add_subplot(gs1[2,:], sharey=ax2)

ax4=fig.add_subplot(gs1[3,:]) #<- want this spaced farther down than the above three axes

plt.show()
```

Comment: A work around with constrained layout would be to put an artist on the axes that makes the space for you.  This could be the title.  Or it could be a patch the same color as the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution -- here I first added a gridspec for the first three plots. This I specified should finish at 0.35 from the bottom (0 being the very bottom, 1 the top). Then I added another gridspec that starts at 0.3 and so has a gap of 0.05. Obviously you can play around with the numbers/placement.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,12))
gs1=fig.add_gridspec(nrows=3, ncols=1, hspace=0, bottom=0.35)

ax1=fig.add_subplot(gs1[0,0])
ax2=fig.add_subplot(gs1[1,0], sharey=ax1)
ax3=fig.add_subplot(gs1[2,0], sharey=ax1)

gs2=fig.add_gridspec(nrows=1, ncols=1, top=0.3)
ax4=fig.add_subplot(gs2[0,0])

for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xticks([])

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]